# "Last week I had" vs "Last week I have"

Tags: have

What is the difference between

"Last week I have started" and "Last week I had started" ?

Is the first sentence correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do the tenses and aspects in English correspond temporally to one another?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21846/how-do-the-tenses-and-aspects-in-english-correspond-temporally-to-one-another)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the first one is not correct. You are talking about a point in the past, and therefore need to use past tense.

> Last week I start...
>   Last week I have started...

These are both using the present tense (present perfect for the second example). Both are wrong.

> Last week I started...
>   Last week I had started...

These are both using the past tense (past perfect for the second example). Both are correct (assuming the rest of the sentence fits the tense you are using, of course)

---

However, there are ways that you can rephrase the original sentence and use present perfect tense while still being grammatically correct. Some examples that come to mind:

> *Since* last week, I have started hearing sounds coming from the attic at night.
>   *Because of what happened* last week, I have stopped feeding gremlins after midnight.